# how to use setuptools to install lupa with python

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, lua, lupa

when i install lupa happen errors.

ENV: python2.7 32bits

vcforpython

visual studio 2017
errors:

    `C:\Users\wangxin\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -ID:\lupa-1.6\LuaJIT-2.0.5\src -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC /Tclupa/_lupa.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\lupa/_lupa.obj
_lupa.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\include\vcruntime.h(96) : warning C4005: '_CRT_STRINGIZE' : macro redefinition
        C:\Users\wangxin\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Include\crtdefs.h(180) : see previous definition of '_CRT_STRINGIZE'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\include\vcruntime.h(99) : warning C4005: '_CRT_WIDE' : macro redefinition
        C:\Users\wangxin\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Include\crtdefs.h(185) : see previous definition of '_CRT_WIDE'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\include\vcruntime.h(142) : warning C4005: '__CRTDECL' : macro redefinition
        C:\Users\wangxin\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Include\crtdefs.h(650) : see previous definition of '__CRTDECL'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\include\vcruntime.h(196) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier '__vcrt_bool'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\include\vcruntime.h(196) : error C2059: syntax error : ';'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\include\stdint.h(111) : warning C4005: 'WCHAR_MIN' : macro redefinition
        C:\Users\wangxin\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Include\wchar.h(43) : see previous definition of 'WCHAR_MIN'
error: command 'C:\\Users\\wangxin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2`

help!Thanks

Comment: I'd be very surprised if the Python 2.7 distro was built with Visual Studio 2017. Can you find you which compiler they used (maybe VS2010? but it's hopefully in the documentation) and try that?

Comment: In any case you might be better just installing Anaconda's Python 2.7 (or miniconda's). They have binary packages of lupa you can just pip install I think.

Comment: i try install Anaconda and pip install lupa,but it still happen errors.   UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 13-50: ordinal not in range(128)

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\wangxin\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-qjym3p\lupa\